# AWK sort array by splitting string on particular column to match another array in bash

Tags: arrays, bash, awk

I have an array `a` that the following lines

```
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000188976 ENST00000487214
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000187961 ENST00000622660
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   84069   NM_001160184.1
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  NC_006462594.2
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XR_001737138.1
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XM_006710600.3
```

and another ordered array `b` that has the following lines:

```
NC
NG
NM
NP
NR
XM
XP
XR
WP
```

I would like to order the lines in array `a` to match the order of array `b` on column 5 to obtain to desired output:

```
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  NC_006462594.2
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   84069   NM_001160184.1
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XM_006710600.3
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XR_001737138.1
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000188976 ENST00000487214
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000187961 ENST00000622660
```

I tried to do the following command by splitting on column 5 but it is printing blank lines:

```
awk -F '\t' -v OFS='\t' 'FNR==NR{split(a[$5],t,"_"); t[1]=$0;next}
{print a[$1]}' <(printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}") <(printf '%s\n' "${b[@]}")
```

Could you please tell me why my command is not working ? Would a partial match by regex work ?

**EDIT 1**: changing array `a` to include lines that can have multiple codes from array `b`

```
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000188976 ENST00000487214
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000187961 ENST00000622660
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   84069   NM_001160184.1
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  NC_006462594.2
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000135234 ENST00000624144
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XR_001737138.1
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   334324  NC_006462632.2
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   84333   NM_004353462.1
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XM_006710600.3
```

Expected output:

```
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   334324  NC_006462632.2
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  NC_006462594.2
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   84069   NM_001160184.1
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   84333   NM_004353462.1
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XM_006710600.3
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XR_001737138.1
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000188976 ENST00000487214
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000187961 ENST00000622660
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000135234 ENST00000624144
```

**EDIT 2**: Since the answer provided by RavinderSingh13 below did not fully answer my question, I will re-ask the question on how to perform such task with AWK.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did you put the lines where $5 does not contain a _ at the end of the desired output?

Comment: Can there be multiple `NC_` lines in array `a` ?

Comment: @hek2mgl I used $5 because I though it would take 5th column which contains string like `XR_001737138.1` and it would split them on `_` ...

Comment: @anubhava yes there can be multiple NC lines in `a`

Comment: @Law Read my question carefully

Comment: oh I am sorry I have misunderstood what you meant. I still want them to be printed at the bottom of the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming here that you want to print matching fields of both arrays in order and then remaining non-matched items from array a also you want to print too, if that is the case then following may help you here.

Creating arrays here:

```
declare -a a=("rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000188976 ENST00000487214
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000187961 ENST00000622660
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   84069   NM_001160184.1
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  NC_006462594.2
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XR_001737138.1
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XM_006710600.3")
declare -a b=("NC
NG
NM
NP
NR
XM
XP
XR
WP")
```

Now running following code:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
FNR==NR{
  split($5,a,"_")
  array[a[1]]=$0
  next
}
($1 in array) {
  print array[$0]
  b[$1]
}
END{
  for(i in b){
    delete array[i]
  }
  for(j in array){
    print array[j]
  }
}' <(printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}") <(printf '%s\n' "${b[@]}")
```

Output will be as follows.

```
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  NC_006462594.2
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   84069   NM_001160184.1
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XM_006710600.3
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XR_001737138.1
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000188976 ENST00000487214
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000187961 ENST00000622660
```

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 when using this code, it outputs the correct order but only one line, for example, the line NM in array a. I only gave a small subset but there can be multiple lines having the same code of array b like so `rs6605071 chr1:962943 C 84069 NM_001160184.1`  `rs6605071 chr1:962943 C 84062 NM_004420144.5`

Comment: I am riding bike as of now. If your actual input_file is not same as shown samples then please do add correct samples. Will look into it once I am on system

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 yes I will edit my post, it's slightly different since I only wanted to keep it as simple as possible

Comment: Bump on this post to have some feedback on the newly edited code ... sorry