# Sort array with multiple lines using another ordered array pattern in bash with awk

Tags: arrays, awk

Following my previous post on [my old post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54580144/awk-sort-array-by-splitting-string-on-particular-column-to-match-another-array-i) and since it didn't fully answer my question. I would like to know how can I sort my array `a` containing multiple lines of a particular tag code from array `b`.

I have an array `a` that the following lines

```
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000188976 ENST00000487214 stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000187961 ENST00000622660 stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   84069   NM_001160184.1  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  NC_006462594.2  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000135234 ENST00000624144 stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XR_001737138.1  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   334324  NC_006462632.2  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   84333   NM_004353462.1  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XM_006710600.3  stuff
```

and another ordered array `b` that has the following lines:

```
NC
NG
NM
NP
NR
XM
XP
XR
WP
```

I would like to order the lines in array `a` to match the order of array `b` on column 5 to obtain to desired output:

```
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   334324  NC_006462632.2  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  NC_006462594.2  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   84069   NM_001160184.1  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   84333   NM_004353462.1  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XM_006710600.3  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XR_001737138.1  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000188976 ENST00000487214 stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000187961 ENST00000622660 stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000135234 ENST00000624144 stuff
```

The following command has been proposed in my previous post:

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
FNR==NR{
  split($5,a,"_")
  array[a[1]]=$0
  next
}
($1 in array) {
  print array[$0]
  b[$1]
}
END{
  for(i in b){
    delete array[i]
  }
  for(j in array){
    print array[j]
  }
}' <(printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}") <(printf '%s\n' "${b[@]}")
```

but it prints:

```
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   334324  NC_006462632.2  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   84069   NM_001160184.1  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XM_006710600.3  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XR_001737138.1  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000188976 ENST00000487214 stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000187961 ENST00000622660 stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000135234 ENST00000624144 stuff
```

As you see, there are lines containing `NM` and `NC` missing. Could you please tell me how I can update this command to output the desired result ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say b is ordered, what do you mean? Your example appears to be sorted alphabetically, except that WP is not in the right place

Comment: Do you care about the order of b, or do you just want a and b to match?

Comment: @jhnc what I meant is that array `b` is sorted according to a fixed pattern and not alphabetically. It just happened to be this way but it could be the other way around, it's called associative arrays in bash. check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29161323/how-to-keep-associative-array-order-in-bash). So, the order of `b` must not change and the lines of array `a` has to match the order of array `b`. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try following. I have changed solution a bit now. Why because it was not clear that you want to print ALL values of for example `NC` from array a so I have changed the logic now. Where it will keep concatenating values to itself for a string `NC` OR `NV` and when it checks it in array b or so then it will print all values of it(from array a).

```
awk -v OFS='\t' '
FNR==NR{
  split($5,a,"_")
  array[a[1]]=(array[a[1]]?array[a[1]] ORS $0:$0)
  next
}
($1 in array) {
  print array[$0]
  delete array[$0]
}
END{
  for(j in array){
   if(array[j]){ print array[j] }
  }
}' <(printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}") <(printf '%s\n' "${b[@]}")
```

Comment: Thanks again for the answer !  it's a clear code again ! :)

Answer (score 2):

here is `awk` with `sort` solution

```
$ awk 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=NR; next} 
          {k=substr($5,1,2); 
           print (k in a)?a[k]:99,NR "\t" $0}' <(printf '%s\n' "${b[@]}") <(printf '%s\n' "${a[@]}") | 
  sort -n | cut -f2-

rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  NC_006462594.2  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   334324  NC_006462632.2  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   84069   NM_001160184.1  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   84333   NM_004353462.1  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XM_006710600.3  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   339451  XR_001737138.1  stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000188976 ENST00000487214 stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000187961 ENST00000622660 stuff
rs6605071   chr1:962943 C   ENSG00000135234 ENST00000624144 stuff
```

Comment: @karafka thank you for the answer ! Could you please explain keep what awk did ?

Comment: I also request that you could keep this comment please because other users may find it useful and answer their questions because of how simple it is as one liner !

Answer (score 1):

You can try this awk. Wll be memory dependant (problem on huge file) because load the dictionnary but also the full file in an temporary array. Need a GNU version for the use of asort.

```
awk 'FNR==NR{ Dct[$1] = Idx++; next }
   {
   Ctg = $5; sub( /_.*/, "", Ctg )
   Indice = ( Ctg in Dct ) ? Dct[Ctg] : Idx
   Lines[Ln++] = Indice " " $0
   }

   END {
     asort( Lines )
     for( Idx=0; Idx<Ln; Idx++) {
        Temp = Lines[Idx]
        sub( /^[^ ]* /, "", Temp)
        print Temp
        }
     }
   ' Array.B Array.A
```

same principle of @karakfa but only in awk